# Programming environment app

Tags: apps

There is an app (I think by Microsoft) that lets you write programs using its scripting language.

The programs you write run inside the app itself.

Does anyone know what it's called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's TouchDevelop from Microsoft Research.

Link to the app in the Marketplace
http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=fe08ccec-a360-e011-81d2-78e7d1fa76f8

Link to the Project
http://www.touchdevelop.com/